# Poreach and michyah in Negaim

Tags: mishna, tzaraas-negaim

I've been trying to learn the [middle perakim](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Negaim.6.2?lang=bi) in Negaim (say, 6 through 8), and I'm having trouble with what seems like a simple question on many of the mishnayos:
A מחיה is usually translated as, healthy skin. Normal looking skin.
פורח means, completely covered by the nega (some areas don't need to be covered, like the head or the ראשי אברים).
Question is, How do you tell what you're looking at? [For instance](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Negaim.8.9?lang=bi&namedEntity=rabbi-yishmael-b-elisha&namedEntityText=%D7%A8%D6%B7%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%99%D6%B4%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B0%D7%9E%D6%B8%D7%A2%D6%B5%D7%90%D7%9C&with=Lexicon&lang2=en):

> הַבָּא כֻלּוֹ לָבָן וּבוֹ מִחְיָה כָעֲדָשָׁה, פָּרְחָה בְכֻלּוֹ
> וְאַחַר כָּךְ חָזְרוּ בוֹ רָאשֵׁי אֵבָרִים
> If one came with his whole body white, and on it there was healthy flesh
> to the extent of a lentil, and then the nega spread out covering all
> his skin, and then the ends of his limbs reappeared...

So he was originally *completely covered except for one place with healthy flesh* (and then it's tamei right now, like any nega that shows up originally with a מחיה). How is that different from, *not completely covered* (and he's only confined)?
Or, פָּרְחָה בְכֻלּוֹ - "spread to cover all his skin". How is that different from, "the מחיה went away"?

I have related questions in a number of earlier mishnayos. For example, [mishnah 6:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Negaim.6.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that according to the Chachamim, a nega with a מחיה cannot spread *inward* into the healthy flesh, that's not called "spreading", has to go the other way. So is that later mishnah called "inward"? He was all one big nega except for that healthy flesh, so why isn't that "inward"?
If he was a little less covered, more than 50% covered except for a little מחיה inside, is the מחיה called "inside" and the remaining 40% "outside"?
Does someone say you can distinguish מחיה from actually healthy skin?

Update: The question also appears earlier, 4:3:

יֵשׁ בְּשֵׂעָר לָבָן מַה שֶּׁאֵין בְּמִחְיָה, וְיֵשׁ בְּמִחְיָה מַה שֶּׁאֵין בְּשֵׂעָר לָבָן. כו' שֶׁהַמִּחְיָה כו' וּמְעַכֶּבֶת אֶת הַהוֹפֵךְ כֻּלּוֹ לָבָן,כו' מַה שֶּׁאֵין כֵּן בְּשֵׂעָר לָבָן:
The mishnah says that a michyah blocks the nega from being tahor when it spreads to the whole body. Well, yeah, because now it didn't spread to the whole body!

Comment: @JoelK Edited to fix this.

Comment: In the Mishna from Chapter 6 you are referring to, the Michya was barely large enough to qualify as a sign of Tumah. Therefore, when the Nega spread inward, the Michya was no longer a sign of Tumah and became Tahor according to the Sages. But if the Michya is larger than a lentil there is no need for spreading to make the Nega Tamei - the Michya is a sign on its own.

So the dispute between Rabbi Meir and the Chachamim on inward spreading is only important in a very specific case.

Comment: @DanielKagan Thank you, Daniel. But according to R' Meir, the michyah is no longer a sign of tumah, but the spread inward counts as a sign of "spreading" instead. According to the Sages, _inward doesn't count_ as "spreading", and the michyah is now too small. - My question is for my mishnah 8:9, is that called "inward"? Why not? - his whole body is a nega with one michyah, and that michyah is shrinking.